# "She allowed her life to be a circumstance of her illness"

Tags: nouns, word-usage

> I never witnessed where she allowed her life to be a circumstance of her illness

Is *circumstance* used in the correct manner? I want to say she didn't use her illness as an excuse to be sick... despite her illness she led an active and fun life!

Comment: Perhaps this is more suited for writers.stackexchange.com

Comment: I think you have more problems that you realize: that *witnessed where* doesn’t sound so good.

Answer (score 0):

Circumstance feels like the wrong word choice. Your paraphrase makes much more sense; maybe you could work from there? Here are some other examples:

> She never used her illness as an excuse for living a less active life.
>
> She never allowed her illness to limit her life.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write, "I never saw her allow her life to be compromised by her illness."

It's not that the other suggestions are *wrong*; it's the *flavor* that word choice extends to the sentence.

Comment: Being in a somewhat darker frame of mind, I'd interpret the sentence as "I *am* Leprosy, which also happens to be alive". In either case, the proper slant on meaning can likely be derived from context.